# Google Maps Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe

There are quite a few people here that had this problem, but the solutions I found aren't working.

Here is the iframe embed code that I got from Google Maps:

```
<iframe width="640" height="480" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=216410867472561730082.0004d44aa7eec841d333d&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=40.696778,-73.978543&amp;spn=0.015618,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small>View <a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=216410867472561730082.0004d44aa7eec841d333d&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;ll=40.696778,-73.978543&amp;spn=0.015618,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">Taskeyo Example 2</a> in a larger map</small>
```

The console says

```
Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.
```

followed by a lot of unsafe JS errors.

The embed code already has &output=embed in it, which seems to be the fix that I need.

Anyone else ever get this error? I only wrapped the iframe in a div (inside a jQuery UI accordion) and it used to work! I appreciate the help.

Comment: do you know which browsers they are using?

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)